# awk array using number as value did not work

Tags: awk, array

I have a reference file:

### Refrence File

```
Dpse\GA30012    FBgn0000447 chr2    26607738    26607962    -1
Dpse\GA19764    FBgn0085819 chrX    28571020    28571736    -1
Dpse\ttk    FBgn0000100 chr2    16553824    16561652    -1
Dpse\GA30195    FBgn0085742 chr3    22629640    22630440    -1
```

and a input file:

### file

```
FBgn0000447 1   11  HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1111:20915:34957  255 -
FBgn0000100 1   11  HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1113:9591:98803   255 -
FBgn0085819 1   11  HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1204:9035:56108   255 -
FBgn0085742 1   11  HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1204:9035:56108   255 -
FBgn0037963 47752   47802   HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1215:21263:59372  255 -
FBgn0001257 11527   11577   HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1311:2957:12154   255 -
FBgn0034315 158 208 HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:2113:4139:83177   255 -
FBgn0000559 3316    3365    HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:1926:2031    255 +
FBgn0262975 39033   39082   HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:1726:2030    255 +
FBgn0032505 1   50  HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:5095:2042    255 +
FBgn0005593 403 452 HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:3906:2209    255 +
FBgn0013686 692 741 HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:3218:2247    255 -
FBgn0000556 3793    3842    HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:5288:2041    255 +
FBgn0015521 438 487 HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:5731:2170    255 -
FBgn0033912 1121    1170    HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:8602:2063    255 -
```

I created an empty column between the 1st and 2nd column, the `file` become this output2:

### Output2

```
FBgn0000447     435 485 HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1111:20915:34957  255 -
FBgn0000100     704 754 HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1113:9591:98803   255 -
FBgn0085819     154 204 HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1204:9035:56108   255 -
FBgn0085742     389 439 HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1204:9035:56108   255 -
FBgn0037963     47752   47802   HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1215:21263:59372  255 -
FBgn0001257     11527   11577   HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1311:2957:12154   255 -
FBgn0034315     158 208 HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:2113:4139:83177   255 -
FBgn0000559     3316    3365    HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:1926:2031    255 +
FBgn0262975     39033   39082   HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:1726:2030    255 +
FBgn0032505     1   50  HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:5095:2042    255 +
FBgn0005593     403 452 HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:3906:2209    255 +
FBgn0013686     692 741 HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:3218:2247    255 -
FBgn0000556     3793    3842    HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:5288:2041    255 +
FBgn0015521     438 487 HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:5731:2170    255 -
FBgn0033912     1121    1170    HWI-ST484:183:C167BACXX:7:1101:8602:2063    255 -
```

Here is the ideal output:
For each id in column 1 in the `output2` file, for the corresponding id in column 2 in the `reference file`, fill in the `output2` file column 2 with the value of reference column 3. For each id in column 1 in the `output2` file, for the corresponding id in column 2 in the reference file, output2 file column 3 will be equal to (column 3 + reference 4 - 1) (as a calculation result) and  column 4 will be equal to (column 4 + reference 4 - 1).

This my `current code` and I cannot get my ideal output file:

### Current code

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '
    NR==FNR {a[$2]=$3; b[$2]=$4; next}; 
    {if ($1 in a) $2=a[$1]; print}; 
    {if ($1 in b) $3=b[$1]+$3-1; $4=b[$1]+$4-1; print}
' $ref $output2 > $output3
```

Ideal ouput should look like(for the first 4 rows):

### Output (Desired)

```
FBgn0000447 chr2 26607738   26607748    HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1111:20915:34957  255 -
FBgn0000100 chr2 28571020   28571030    HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1113:9591:98803   255 -
FBgn0085819 chrX 16553824   16553834    HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1204:9035:56108   255 -
FBgn0085742 chr3 22629640   22629650    HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1204:9035:56108   255 -
```

Not sure this is due to there is some restriction of the numeric value in awk array or something else is wrong.
Thanks a lot for help!

P.S. I remember one problem, for the `reference file` not all the ids in column 2 have corresponding values in column 3/4. So is this is why I cannot get values in `output2`, how should I solve this? fill in what with the empty space is the best?
Thanks again

Comment: Please actually **show** your ideal output.

Comment: That code strikes me as weird. Are you sure you didn't mean to have the `if`s on the other side of the braces?

Comment: muru I am actually not sure what should be the correct way to write if I am defining 2 array, can they be in one sentence or I need to separate them in two?

Comment: Your `awk` code does not match your English description. According to your English description of your desired output, you should have `if ($1 in a) $2 = a[$1]; print` and for the second part `if ($1 in b) $3 = b[$1] + $3 - 1; $4 = b[$1] + $4 - 1; print`.

Comment: If the reference file is missing a column in some rows then your reference file is broken and you should fix the file. Go type in a 0 for every missing number.

Comment: @jw013 yes, I mistake the code. but after i correct it and fill in all the empty space with 0 in the reference file, it still did not work...

Comment: @Karli Update your question. You said you corrected your code so update your question and then provide more information about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I used your "raw" input without your whitespace modifications: you don't actually specify that your input field separator is a tab, so awk will use "whitespace" as the field separator -- thus is doesn't matter that you inserted some extra tabs or whatever.

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '
    NR == FNR  {ref3[$2] = $3; ref4[$2] = $4; next}
    $1 in ref3 {
        $3 = $3 + ref4[$1] - 1
        $2 = ref3[$1] OFS ($2 + ref4[$1] - 1)
        print
    }
' reference input
```

```
FBgn0000447 chr2    26607738    26607748    HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1111:20915:34957  255 -
FBgn0000100 chr2    16553824    16553834    HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1113:9591:98803   255 -
FBgn0085819 chrX    28571020    28571030    HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1204:9035:56108   255 -
FBgn0085742 chr3    22629640    22629650    HWI-ST1083:68:C0YYUACXX:8:1204:9035:56108   255 -
```

Comment: This did not work yet. And sorry I just edited the example files and ideal output. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Karli, updated

Comment: thanks but it still did not work...I tried the other way which I used {$7=$6;$6=$5;$5=$4;$4=$3;$3=$2; print} so C2 is not just empty and replace the value with chr...using the previous code. but that also did not work...